# how to not specify all Domain property values when saving Domain instance

Tags: grails, dns, persistence

I am newbie to grails. 
I have User domain class with 85 fields and I am doing an operation to update only address field for example.
Right now for any save operation on the User domain I have to specify all property values, If I miss any the save fails. 
How to setup the domain so that I can only specify the properties I want to update, and not the entire property list?

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. All your other fields should be populated correctly when you call a get() on this object. Can you post some code of how you're updating your field?

Comment: Be aware you can specify global gorm constraints. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html - is it the case that validation fails on the other 84 properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try

```
def userInstance=User.get(params.id)
userInstance.address=params.newAddress
userInstance.save(flush:true)
```

Comment: is there a way foe new instance I can have a constructor whichwill populate some default values in the fields

Comment: if its a new instance then u can try                              `def userInstance.properties=params` and then save userInstance.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) for your address page. Create a command object and use it to validate input from that page. If it goes through that check then you update the User instance and continue.

If you are creating a new User, then create it only once you have collected all the mandatory information